# AE Error : Imager Buffers exceed internal limits. Decrease the memory requirements for the rendering of this frame. (12804)

Tags: video, after-effects

I'm kinda new to AE and having a weird issue while trying to render a 1920x1080 Composition.

After rendering about 10seconds, i get the following error:
[image]

I've checked all of my objects and i have no composition with the large dimensions mentioned in the error.

Did anyone ever bump into this error ? It would greatly help me to hear from the more experienced one.

Cheers,
Shai.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what effects & plugins you're using - certain effects can cause errors like this - repetile used to do similar things when I was using a RAM constrained PC (a few versions ago).

Comment: Guys, seriously - this question is 3 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to know what OS your machine is running and if it's 32 or 64 bit, and the resources as in type of processor (Dual Core, i3, i7?) and how much DRAM is on the motherboard. I am not an After Effects user (yet) but this error appears to be a resource error, which is common to many other video editors.

It would also be helpful to have you describe what you are trying to render in AE. For instance how long is the piece, how many video tracks, what effects are used, etc.

Without knowing your computer's resources is not a show stopper, here are some items to check.

Are you running anything else when AE is trying to render, if so try your render again with nothing running but AE.

If you have a 32 bit machine you may have a 2GB limit on the RAM, which is going to be an issue. Have you tried this on a 64 bit machine with more memory?

What resources do you have AE using besides the requested render? For instance do you have the preview screen on 'auto' size mode, you might try to make the preview smaller and in a 1/4 or 1/2 mode so AE doesn't have to figure out each display frame size thereby freeing up some cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It's a MacBook Pro 17" ,i7 2.4, 8GB Ram. I fixed it though, apparently it was CC RepeTile repeating too many times :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It might also be that your project is set at 16-bit, but your photography is in 8-bit.

You can change the bit in project settings or at the bottom of the Project folder to the left of the UI.

Comment: It says in the screenshot that his project is 8bit.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to raytrace 3d work. it turned out that the company has not updated adobe lib optix. in the parts that comes with the after effect is version 3.0.0 in August 2013. It is not present in the card support on the architecture "maxwell"

I downloaded from the site Nvidia optix version 3.8 and simply replace the file optix.1.dll. and lo and behold I have on my card earned ray-trace 3d.
I checked today at work on a gtx 970 and bonded 2x gtx 980 all worked fine

mini guide

1. Download https://www.sendspace.com/file/lt8trf
2. create one backup c: \ Program Files \ Adobe \ Adobe After Effects CC 2014 \ Support Files \ optix.1.dll I just renamed optix.1.dll in optix.1_bak.dll
3. Copy the downloaded file in the c: \ Program Files \ Adobe \ Adobe After Effects CC 2014 \ Support Files \
4. In the after effect turn "Enable untested, unsupported CPU for CUDA acceleration or ray-traced 3D renderer" or you can add your card in the c: \ Program Files \ Adobe \ Adobe After Effects CC 2014 \ Support Files \ raytracer_supported_cards.txt
5. Profit

Screenshots

http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/zJxzSUA%2BuKBdr0L0Gtea6Q

GPU work:gtx 750 ti, gtx 970, gtx 980, gtx 980 ti, gtx titan X. A few mobile gpu from 8xxm series.

I wrote on the forum adobe. but this instruction and criticism towards their company, they are removed

Comment: Dmitri - the OP already commented on the accepted answer what the problem boiled down to.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because of motion blur. Deactivate it or change the movement of your layers if they pass close to the camera.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you expand on why it's related to motion blur? I suspect you might be right but some explanatory detail would go a long way.